# Favoritism granted in politics or business regardless of merit?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes *favoritism granted in politics or business regardless of merit*, but not just towards relatives.

Comment: Old boy's network... Old school tie

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention relatives, I assume you are discarding *nepotism* but you shouldn't, it is exactly the word you are looking for. While the original meaning does imply a blood relation it is often used to refer to favors done to friends as well. See, for example, [this definition](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nepotism):

> favouritism shown to relatives **or close friends** by those with power or influence

Another good option is [*cronyism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cronyism):

> Favoritism shown to old friends without regard for their qualifications, as in political appointments to office.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use cronyism in that setting. It works especially well if you are trying to imply a degree of corruption as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's always *favouritism*!

Thesaurus.com gives as synonyms for *nepotism* (which comes from *nepos*, Latin for *nephew*, so is generally restricted to relatives):

bias
discrimination
inequity
partisanship
partiality
preference
one-sidedness
preferential treatment

Answer (score 0):

Consider *[patronage](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/patronage?view=uk)*

> the power to control appointments to office or the right to privileges:
>   *recruits are selected on merit, not through political patronage*